# SAPI grammar recognition

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-7, sapi

I'm designing an app that is able to recognize the voice on Delphi7

I have no problem with the code ... just that I can not or rather can not find how to make this I recognize a language other than English ... I ate every forum .. I know in search of something to tell me. I tried changing the GRAMMAR C0A LANGID to no avail
install other languages ​​... and still can not get my app to recognize the Spanish language that is where I turn to you have if anyone has run into this problem and want to share me some solution ...

Comment: Have you tried [`the lang`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717077(VS.85).aspx) tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed an appropriate language recognizer?   The recognizers are part of the language packs for Windows 7, Windows 8, and Vista.

As far as I can tell, there are no Spanish language recognizers for SAPI 5.1 (for Windows XP) available from Microsoft.

Comment: @Marthianfred Looks like you're out of luck, then.  The only SAPI version available for XP is SAPI 5.1, which doesn't seem to have any Spanish recognizers.

Comment: Why keep on using WinXP? It's only [a month away from oblivion](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/end-of-support.aspx)